# Why is $.get() not working? $.ajax() is working fine though

Tags: jquery, ajax

//The AJAX here will not work on local files, but will on the github link.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/php; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>AJAX</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>This is  some sdvs</p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.get("info.txt", function(data) {
                alert(data);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

//This is the body of the code where the AJAX get request works on local files. Why does it work on here, but not in the first file?

```
<body>
  <button id="cat-button">magical cat button</button>
  <div id="images">
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $("#cat-button").on("click", function() {
      var queryURL = "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/random?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&tag=cats";
      $.ajax({
        url: queryURL,
        method: "GET"
      })
        .then(function(response) {
          var imageUrl = response.data.image_original_url;
          var catImage = $("<img>");
          catImage.attr("src", imageUrl);
          catImage.attr("alt", "cat image");
          $("#images").prepend(catImage);
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what does *"will not work"* mean? what is *"the github link"*?   also, would you mind cleaning up your question title?

Comment: Browsers disable access to local `file://` protocol access due to security reasons. Are you running your file from a local web server?

Comment: This is the first file link in github: https://vpvamsik1.github.io/AJAX/

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because in the first version, you haven't checked if jQuery is loaded before executing the $.get().

Try wrapping your JS within the following...

```
$.function() {
    //$.get() here
 }
```

Comment: It did not work. The AJAX for the 1st code does work on the github link though.

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"